# Delete a sub sub array (all elements)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema (I removed some unnecessary bits):

```
var VoteSchema = new Schema({
    voter: String,
    val: {type:Number, max:1, min:-1},
    voted_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments: [{type:String, trim:true}]
});

var LexicalEntrySchema = new Schema({
    label:{type:String,trim:true, index:true},

    images:[{
        image_uri: {type:String,trim:true},
        description: String,
        votes:[ { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Vote'} ]
    }],
});
```

I want to delete all the votes in all the images in all the lexical entries. How could this be done?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Because the way you asked it sound like  you want somebody here to solve the problem for you, and not like you would like to overcome some impediment to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do three queries:

1. Do a `LexicalEntry.find` with any filters you require. Use `{images.votes: 1}` as your projection parameter.
2. Do a `LexicalEntry.update` and update all the matching documents found in step 1. `{$set: {"images.votes": []}}`.
3. Remove the vote documents that were left behind: `Votes.remove` with all of the ids that you gathered in step 1.

---

As you might guess, this is rather sub-optimal. You should take advantage of Mongo's capability to embed documents:

```
var LexicalEntrySchema = new Schema({
    label:{type:String,trim:true, index:true},

    images:[{
        image_uri: {type:String,trim:true},
        description: String,
        votes: [ VoteSchema ]
    }]
});
```

Insert new votes by doing: `someEntryDocument.images[0].votes.push({voter: ..., val: ...})`.

Remove votes by doing: `someEntryDocument.images[0].votes = []`.

Mongoose's population feature is best suited for many-many relationships.